# Subspace of $L^2(U)$ that are closed under multiplication?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is non-empty, bounded, open,  connected with $C^1$ boundary. Is there any subspace of $L^2(U)$ that are closed under multiplication, that is under which conditions can we say that
$$ u ,v \in L^2(U)  \implies uv \in L^2(U).$$
I know that in general you can it's easy to prove that 
$$ u ,v \in L^2(U)  \implies uv \in L^1(U)$$ 
by the Hölder inequality, but how could you prove that $uv \in L^2(U)$ with some conditions on $u$ and $v$?

Comment: If $u, v \in L^4(U)$, then $u \, v \in L^2(U)$ (but not in $L^4(U)$. Is this what you are looking for? If $u, v \in L^\infty(U)$, then even $u \, v \in L^\infty(U)$.

Comment: Do you have something in mind? For example: The space $C_0^\infty (\overline{U})$ is closed under multiplication. Also the space of constant functions satisfies it.

Comment: Yes, actually the answer from gerw was just what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question, but it solves my problem.